# How to access date member variable from a returned array object

Tags: php, sql-server, datetime

I am trying to get the current date/time from SQL 2008 database server using PHP.
When I do a dump on the return variable I see the following -

```
array (size=1) <br />
  'current_date_time' =>  <br />
    object(DateTime)[1] <br />
      **public 'date' => string '2012-12-18 15:01:35' (length=19)** <br />
      public 'timezone_type' => int 3 <br />
      public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3) <br />
```

Question: How do I access the 'date' variable only? I tried the following but did not work:

`return $row["current_date_time"]->date`

Comment: What does "_did not work_" mean: do you get an error?

Comment: Yes i get an error, Notice: Undefined property: DateTime::$date in C:\wamp\www\cccac\cccac_functions.php on line 378

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$row["current_date_time"]->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Should do what you need. It looks like `$row["current_date_time"]` is a [DateTime](http://nz1.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object.